# combine very large number of large npy files into one file

Tags: python-3.x, linux, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is it possible to use the `cat` Linux command to concatenate `.npy` files? What is the best and fastest approach to combine a very large number of large `npy` files into one file without loading them?

That is, concatenate NumPy arrays of shape `(20000,1024)` from 1.2M `npy` files into one NumPy array `(1.2M*20000,1024)` and save it to as a new `npy` file.

Comment: Expand on what you mean by combine or concatenate.  What arrays do they contain (shape, dtype)?  How do you expect to use the result?  Are you familiar with the `zip/archive` tools on your operating system?  `np.savez` saves multiple arrays as a `zip` archive, one `npy` file per array.  `np.load` can load those.

Comment: concatenate numpy arrays of shape (20000,1024)in 1.2M npy files into one numpy array (1.2M*20000,1024)  and save it to a new npy file